# Magento, Adding external <script> and <style> in cms blocks?

Tags: magento

I already done my static blocks and linked them to category pages, but now every block has its css and script inside the every page, I want to move them to one css file and one script file, so if I need to make any change it will be done in all pages at ones rather that doing it one by one.

I hope I was clear.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: you need to add js file in the particular page?

Comment: Hi Meenakshi, I already have same scc and same js in every cms block, I need to move them outside and link them to all cms blocks, Thank you for reply

Comment: ok need add css and js in all cms page right

Comment: I need to link css and js to the cms blocks

Comment: link means you want add some js file in your cms page?